# Empty before properties when routing a non office document with content organizing rules

Tags: 2010

I have an event reiver which checks if some metadata has changed if so (and if it's set to the corect value) then an email has will be sent

When I upload a document in my drop off library and set the metadata the document is being routed to another library due to the content organizing rules.

I expect only one mail, the strange thing is when I upload a non office document I get 2 mails.

What happens is the following:

- upload document
- save metata
- itemupdated (1ste time)

-move document to corresponding library (content organizer rules)

- itemupdated (2nd time)

The problem is with the 2nd itemupdated. When I upload an office document in the 2nd itemupdated the beforeproprties of the metadata I filled in are filled. But when I use a non office document (for example txt or pdf) then the before properties are empty in the 2nd itemupdated. But they should be filled in, because the item is already been updated.

Can anyone clarify my problem?